# Building a Weighted Undirected Graph

Tags: java, linked-list, undirected-graph, weighted-graph

I'm working on a coding challenge in Java where my driver reads in the names of cities and the mileages between them from text files.  This information is then going to be passed to a method which will populate a weighted, undirected graph. The city names are the nodes and the mileages between them are the weights.  I am writing the Graph class, and I'm using a Linked List data type for the adjacency matrix.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class WeightedGraph {

    static class Edge
    {
        String origin;
        String destination;
        int weight;

        public Edge(String origin, String destination, int weight)
        {
            this.origin = origin;
            this.destination = destination;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    }

    static class Graph
    {
        int numVertices;
        LinkedList<Edge>[] adjList;

        Graph(int numVertices)
        {
            this.numVertices = numVertices;
            adjList = new LinkedList[numVertices];

            for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
            {
                adjList[i] = new LinkedList<>();
            }
        }

    }

    public void addUndirectedEdge(String origin, String destination, int weight)
    {
        Edge edge = new Edge(origin, destination, weight);
        adjList[origin].add(edge);
        adjList[destination].add(edge);
    }
}
```

---

In the example I'm working from, the nodes are numbered, not named, and the variables "origin" and "destination" are integers.  It was proposed that I need to get the index values for the strings and use those in the lines:

```
        adjList[origin].add(edge);
        adjList[destination].add(edge);
```

which are in the addUndirectedEdge method.  How do I do that?
Do I need to declare the variables "origin" and "domain" as integers instead of strings?

Comment: You can only index into a linked list using an integer, but you're trying to do it with a String. You need to find the index where that String is, and use that instead.

Comment: How do I do that?  In the example I'm working off of, the nodes are numbered not named, so it's easier.

Comment: Is there a requirement of using a LinkedList<Edge>? For the purpose of the requirements listed would a Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> (Map<Origin, Map<Destination, Weight>>) work out?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Map.

Answer (score 0):

```
    adjList[origin].add(edge);
    adjList[destination].add(edge);
```

Origin and destination are string here. And you are trying to get array item by string.

Answer (score 0):

In the language of your IDE:

Expected: `adjList[int]`

Found: `adjList[String]`